# How to refresh GridView without moving it?

Tags: android, arrays, gridview

```
public void UpdateData(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> array_list){
  GridView glist = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.tipss_grid)
  adapter2 =new CurrentAdapter(CurrentChanels.this,array_list);
  glist.setAdapter(adapter2);

}
```

I call this method to populate data in `gridview`. I m displaying currently running programs. After every 1 min I call this method to refresh the data. The problem is that when user is on the last element of `gridview` and mean while I refresh it then control move to top of the screen. I do not want the screen to move,it must stay where it is before refresh. Any suggestions?

Comment: use `adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Its not working if I don't call setadapter after it. Calling setadapter move the screen to top.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by User is in the last element? Do you mean he scrolled down to the last elements(with out actually selecting any grid item)?

Comment: declare the ArrayList of your items as a global variable, and then , when you modify it ( for example : `items.add(newItem);`) call `adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();`) and it will works

Comment: yes exactly. user scrolled down to any position from 1 to 40. I don't want to move the screen while refresh the data so that user can remain where it was before refresh.

Comment: thank you everyone for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because every one minute you are creating a new Adapter and assigning it to the GridView.

Implement a new method resetData() in CurrentAdapter:

```
public void resetData(List<HashMap<String,String>> list) {
    _list.clear();
    _list.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Call resetData() whenever you want to refresh the grid:

```
GridView glist = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.tipss_grid);
if (glist.getAdapter() == null) {
    CurrentAdapter adapter2 = new CurrentAdapter(CurrentChanels.this,
         array_list);
    glist.setAdapter(adapter2);
} else {
    CurrentAdapter adapter2 = ((CurrentAdapter)glist.getAdapter());
    adapter2.resetData(array_list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this line after setadapter line

```
glist.setSelection(adapter2.getCount() - 1) ;
```

Comment: I have 40 elements in GridView. User can be on any position. I just gave example of last element.If user is on 20th positions then?

Answer (score 0):

You can call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but if you creating new ArrayList you have to set new adapter. You should change data in old ArrayList if you want notifyDataSetChanged() work.